# Convert the each column of the dataframe in a list in to as.POSIXct

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes i want convert in to each column of the dataframe in to time stamp

```
gg=list(a = data.frame(X1 = c(1516087622, 1516087622, 1516087622, 1516087622, 
1516087622), X2 = c(1516087622, 1516087622, 1516087622, 1516087622, 
1516087622)),b = data.frame(X1 = c(1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 
1516078740), X2 = c(1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 
1516078740)))

> gg
$a
          X1         X2
1 1516087622 1516087622
2 1516087622 1516087622
3 1516087622 1516087622
4 1516087622 1516087622
5 1516087622 1516087622

$b
          X1         X2
1 1516078740 1516078740
2 1516078740 1516078740
3 1516078740 1516078740
4 1516078740 1516078740
5 1516078740 1516078740
```

I am using the following function

```
Map(as.POSIXct,lapply(gg,function(x) x[[1]]),origin = "1970-01-01")
```

it's convert the first column of the each dataframe 
but i want convert all at a time ..

I need base R function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We `map` through the `list` elements and with `mutate_all` change all the columns to `POSIXct` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(gg, ~ .x %>% 
            mutate_all(funs(as.POSIXct(., origin = "1970-01-01"))))
#$a
#                   X1                  X2
#1 2018-01-16 12:57:02 2018-01-16 12:57:02
#2 2018-01-16 12:57:02 2018-01-16 12:57:02
#3 2018-01-16 12:57:02 2018-01-16 12:57:02
#4 2018-01-16 12:57:02 2018-01-16 12:57:02
#5 2018-01-16 12:57:02 2018-01-16 12:57:02

#$b
#                   X1                  X2
#1 2018-01-16 10:29:00 2018-01-16 10:29:00
#2 2018-01-16 10:29:00 2018-01-16 10:29:00
#3 2018-01-16 10:29:00 2018-01-16 10:29:00
#4 2018-01-16 10:29:00 2018-01-16 10:29:00
#5 2018-01-16 10:29:00 2018-01-16 10:29:00
```

---

The corresponding `base R` option would be to loop through the `list` elements with `Map`, then loop through each column of the dataset with `lapply` and assign the transformed value to the dataset (`x[] <-`), return the dataset

```
Map(function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.POSIXct, origin = "1970-01-01");x }, gg)
```

Comment: Thankyou for explanation.@ akrun

Comment: How can we change selected columns like second column in using above function.

Comment: @user7462639  You meant to say that only select a particular column>  In that case `Map(function(x){ x[,2] <- as.POSIXct(x[,2], origin = "1970-01-01"); x}, gg)`